AWS CodePipeline won't create build folder for ReactJS application to Elastic Beanstalk
I'm using AWS codepipeline. I would like to automatize the process of pushing my frontend to github. Then the pipeline would build my frontend, and push it to elastic beanstalk.
In the first picture you can see the context of my directory at local, I only push the context of the directory to the git.
In the second picture you can see the context of my buildspec.yml
In the third picture you can see that the build file actually being created, and the artifacts are successfully being uploaded, yet Elastic Beanstalk does not find the package.json or the build file



I SSH into the elastic beanstalk, and i can clearly see that under /var/app/ there is a current folder, which should have the build file. It does not have but it does have

buildspec.yml,  node_modules, package.json, package-lock.json, Procfile,
public, README.md, server.js, src

Yet Elastic Beanstalk would search for index html under /var/app/current/build/index.html

Does deploying to EB work outside the context of codepipeline and Github actions? Are you able to execute EB-CLI commands to get it to work ?
